# How to splt pdf file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to split selected pdf file.
Like i have a pdf file having 1o page then i want to split pdf file in 10 pdf having one page each pdf file.
I will select this pdf file using input type=file. Please help me i have a urgent requirement to complete this issues.(Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do is not possible via javascript unless you're able to use web services to call a 3rd party application (or alternatively, send the file to the 3rd party application and return the results).

PDF files contain common information that's shared among all the pages, including the page layout, how to print each page, color matching information, the fonts (possibly including the actual font files themselves), and more. To extract a page from a PDF file, you need an application like Adobe Acrobat Exchange or similar.